# Fit data to curve using polyfit with multiple variables in python using numpy polyfit

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to calculate the parameters for a polynomial model in two variables. They are independant such that:

```
z = a + bx + cx^2 + dy + ey^2
```

I've been told that you can use `numpy.polyfit` for this but it only can support two variables and not the three that I require. My data is currently stored in three numpy arrays such that the index of each piece of data in the array is associated with the data at that index in the other variables. i.e.

```
Y = [1 2 3 4 5]
X = [3 5 7 9 11]
Z = [2 4 6 2 6]
```

1 is associated with 3 and 2;2 with 5 and 4 and so on.
How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`polyfit` assumes one variable.  However, what you're wanting to do is solve a general linear system of equations.

### Expressing the Problem with Linear Algebra

You have an equation:

```
z = a + bx + cx^2 + dy + ey^2
```

And 5 points where x, y, and z are observed. This gives us 5 equations:

```
z1 = a + bx1 + cx1^2 + dy1 + ey1^2
z2 = a + bx2 + cx2^2 + dy2 + ey2^2
z3 = a + bx3 + cx3^2 + dy3 + ey3^2
z4 = a + bx4 + cx4^2 + dy4 + ey4^2
z5 = a + bx5 + cx5^2 + dy5 + ey5^2
```

It's easiest to think of this as a linear algebra problem.  We can rewrite the set of equations as a matrix multiplication:

```
|z1|   |1  x1  x1^2  y1  y1^2|   |a|
|z2|   |1  x2  x2^2  y2  y2^2|   |b|
|z3| = |1  x3  x3^2  y3  y3^2| x |c|
|z4|   |1  x4  x4^2  y4  y4^2|   |d|
|z5|   |1  x5  x5^2  y5  y5^2|   |e|
```

We know `x1..5`, `y1..5`, and `z1..5`, but  `a, b, c, d, e` are unknowns.  Let's call these matrices `B`, `A`, and `x`, respectively:

```
B = A x
```

We want to solve for `x`, which is a matrix of our `a, b, c, d, e` parameters.

---

### Singular Matrix

However, we have a wrinkle.  The exact numbers you gave for `x`, `y`, and `z` result in a singular matrix for `A`.  In other words, the rows are not independent.  We've effectively put in the same equation twice.  In fact, in this exact case, we only have 3 equations. The other two are just combinations of the first three.

There's no way to solve the system of equations with the X, Y, Z data you supplied.

With that in mind, let's change the problem to use 5 random x,y,z points.

### Exact solution

In this specific case, we have exactly 5 unknowns and 5 equations.  Therefore, we could solve this exactly (e.g. using `np.linalg.solve`).  This is called an "even-determined problem".

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

# Each array with have 5 random points
x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 5))

# A is going to look like:
#  |1  x1  x1^2  y1  y1^2|
#  |1  x2  x2^2  y2  y2^2|
#  |1  x3  x3^2  y3  y3^2|
#  |1  x4  x4^2  y4  y4^2|
#  |1  x5  x5^2  y5  y5^2|
A = np.column_stack([np.ones(len(x)), x, x**2, y, y**2])

# And "B" will just be our "z" array
B = z

# Now we can solve the system of equations Ax = B
a, b, c, d, e = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
```

---

### More Than 5 Observations

However, let's say we had 10 observations or 100.  In that case, we'd have an over-determined problem.  We can't solve it exactly, and instead need to use a least-squares fit.

In that case, you'd still express things in terms of a matrix multiplication and solve `Ax = B`.  However, `A` won't be a square matrix.  Therefore, we need to use different tools to solve the problem.  For `numpy`, it's `np.linalg.lstsq` instead of `np.linalg.solve`:

I'll elaborate on this shortly (may be a bit), but for the moment:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

# Each array with have 20 random points this time
x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 20))

# We're solving Ax = B
A = np.column_stack([np.ones(len(x)), x, x**2, y, y**2])
B = z

# Solve the system of equations.
result, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
a, b, c, d, e = result
```

### Removing Terms

If you wanted to remove the `bx` and `dy` terms from the equation, you'd take them out of `A`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 20))

# Note that we've remove the `x` and `y` terms.
# We're solving `z = a + cx^2 + ey^2`
A = np.column_stack([np.ones(len(x)), x**2, y**2])
B = z

# Solve the system of equations.
result, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
a, c, e = result
```